# Is there way to hide the column id in table using Data table Jquery?

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have an error regarding on columnDefs, I have datatable where I list all the customers data, however I need to hide the first column of the datatable, so the docs of datatable point me to use columnDefs. moving forward in my localhost the columnDefs well work and fine. however in my production the columnDefs give an error.

[image: Error]

**The Question: Why does in my production gives me an error like this?**

I will share to you guys my function where I list all the details of customers,

```
     var details = response.data;

  $.each(details, function (index, el) {

      var stringify = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(el));
      var customer_name_each = stringify['customer_name'];
      var customer_address_each = stringify['customer_address'];
      var customer_email_each = stringify['customer_email'];
      var customer_number_each = stringify['customer_number'];
      var store_location_each = stringify['customer_location'];
      var customer_order_note_each = stringify['customer_order_note'];
      var customer_registered_each = stringify['customer_registered'];
      var customer_id_each = stringify['customer_id'];
      var customer_km = stringify['customer_km'];
      var action_each = '<center><button id="show_cart_button" class="btn btn-primary"  type="button" value='+customer_id_each+' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add_cart" ><i class="fas fa-cart-arrow-down"></i></button></center>';

      var t = $( "#tables" ).DataTable({
        "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
        "bDestroy": true,
        "columnDefs": [
        {
            "targets": [ 0 ],
            "visible": false,
            "searchable": false
        }
        ]
      });
      t.row.add([
        customer_id_each,
        customer_name_each,
        customer_address_each,
        customer_email_each,
        customer_number_each,
        store_location_each,
        customer_km,
        customer_order_note_each,
        customer_registered_each,
        action_each]).draw();

    });
```

**Html:**

```
    <table id="tables" class="table table-striped" style="width:100%;">
        <thead>
            <tr style="font-size:14px;">
                <th scope="col">ID</th>
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Ship to</th>
                <th scope="col">Email</th>
                <th scope="col">Telephone</th>
                <th scope="col">Store Location</th>
                <th>Destination Kilometers</th>
                <th scope="col">Customer Other Details</th>
                <th scope="col">Date Called</th>
                <th scope="col">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody style=" font-size:14px;">

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us the shape of your source data for dev and production?  It seems like maybe one of they keyvals is missing in production.

Comment: what do you mean shape of your source data for dev and production? do i need to show both dev and production files?

Comment: you might want to anonymise the data, but yes. I'd say column 9 is missing in some or all of your records on production. Did you read https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/4 out of interest?

Comment: why does column 9 is missing, the row that i add is both same on localhost and production.

Comment: There's something different in your column 9 data between production and dev, maybe a null value, or something else.

Comment: ok i will tried to echo out the customer_id both production and localhost so it may give more details

Comment: Side note: you should initialize your datatables once instead of doing it at each iteration of your loop.

Answer (score 0):

To Solved The Problem,
This is the code I used to hide the column without error, Thank you.

```
      var t = $( "#tables" ).DataTable({
        "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
        "bDestroy": true,
        // "columnDefs": [
        // {
        //     "targets": [ 0 ],
        //     "visible": false,
        //     "searchable": false
        // }
        // ]
      });
      t.column(0).visible(false);
```